# Trying to find the index values of an array which consist of objects

Tags: javascript, indexing

why is it that i am unable to find the index values of the 'deck' array using **deck[0]** but this notation works for **suits[0]**

I am trying to find the index values of my 'deck' array but i am unsure why i keep getting 'undefined'.

```
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds","hearts","clubs","spades"];
var value = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];


function genDeck()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < value.length; x++){
            var card = {Value:value[x], Suit:suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }
    return deck;
}
window.onload = function () {
    genDeck();
};

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
```

Comment: you forgot to call `deck.push(card)` ?

Comment: i have updated it to include ```deck.push(card)``` but still when i do ```console.log(deck[0]);``` i get undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't adding anything to the deck array. You need to call

`deck.push(card)`

EDIT: Here's the working example code:

```
var deck = [];
var suits = ["diamonds","hearts","clubs","spades"];
var value = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"];


function genDeck()
{

    for(var i = 0; i < suits.length; i++)
    {
        for(var x = 0; x < value.length; x++){
            var card = {Value:value[x], Suit:suits[i]};
            deck.push(card);
        }
    }
    return deck;
}
window.onload = function () {
    genDeck();
    console.log('First Item: ', deck[0])
};

var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
```

Note that you have to call `console.log` after you've called `genDeck` in your `window.onload` function.

Comment: i have updated it to include ```deck.push(card)``` but still when i do ```console.log(deck[0]);``` i get undefined